# Why is DirectoryIterator not going through all my files in php

Tags: php

can anyone tell me why my code is only outputting 20 out of 40 files

```
$Files = array();
  $dir = new DirectoryIterator('./images/gallery');
  foreach($dir as $fileinfo){
    if($fileinfo->isFile()){
      $Files[$fileinfo->getMTime()] = $fileinfo->getFilename();
    }
  }
  krsort($Files);          
  foreach($Files as $file){
    echo "<a rel='fancy1' href='/images/gallery/$file'><span><img src='/images/revelsmashy.php?src=/images/gallery/$file&w=128&zc=0&q=100'></span></a>\n";
  }
```

edit: 
i am looking to sort images based on the data time they were uploaded with the latest one posted 1st

Comment: Is there any pattern to the missed files?

Comment: You are indexing the array by the file `mtime`. If you have duplicates of that value, they will overwrite the previously set key.

Comment: If you are not using the mtime beyond this index (you aren't based on the posted code only), just skip the array index and append with `$Files[] = `

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski i think that may be it! does that mean it doesn't count the second?

Comment: @Triggs It means that the first one gets overwritten, so only the second one with the same mtime value is in your final array.

Comment: @JohnConde no the names and ext are will vary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your original method of indexing the array by the file's modification time looks to be resulting in files having the same `mtime` values overwriting previous array keys. In some circumstances, if your whole directory were rewritten at once, *all* files could have the same modification time so only the *last* one iterated will be in the resultant array.

If you need to ultimately sort by the time, you can instead build a multidimensional array which holds both filenames and file modification times and then sort it using [`usort()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php).

```
$dir = new DirectoryIterator('./images/gallery');
foreach($dir as $fileinfo){
  if($fileinfo->isFile()){
    // Append each file as an array with filename and filetime keys
    $Files[] = array(
      'filename' => $fileinfo->getFilename(), 
      'filetime' => $fileinfo->getMtime()
    );
  }
}

// Then perform a custom sort:
// (note: this method requires PHP 5.3. For PHP <5.3 the you have to use a named function instead.
// see the usort() docs for examples )
usort($Files, function($a, $b) {
  if ($a['filetime'] == $b['filetime']) return 0;
  return $a['filetime'] < $b['filetime'] ? -1 : 1;
});
```

In your output loop, access the `filename` key:

```
foreach($Files as $file){
    echo "<a rel='fancy1' href='/images/gallery/{$file['filename']}'><span><img src='/images/revelsmashy.php?src=/images/gallery/{$file['filename']}&w=128&zc=0&q=100'></span></a>\n";
    //-----------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```